# Field wise Banded Column style

Tags: excel, pivot-table

I want to design pivot table with banned column style and I am using Excel 2013

I have set the style and it looks like below.

[image]

I want to design it Rank wise. Means there three fields Pre, Post, Exp 
per Rank

My expectation is like below

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

What you want is a customized style, follow this steps:

1. Clear all filters in the pivot table
   Select any cell in the pivot table then click in the Ribbon tab: Data \ Group Sort & Filter: Clear (see fig. 1)

[image]

2. Select the Field Items you want to fill with a color
   Keep press the [Ctrl] key while selecting the field items
3. Once selected them fill them with the color you want (see fig.2)

[image]

4. Pivot table customized in fig. 3

[image]

*Be aware that this customizes the interior of each items, so the columns banned is not alternated, it's fix.*

*To keep it alternated the Pivot Table must show all the `Rank` items always. To do that, change the settings of the Field `Rank` in tab `Layout & Print` flag the option `Show items with no data`* *(see Fig. 4)*

[image]

Comment: Sorry I could not reply. As I understand this can work only when Rank has only five value, If its increases I have to format it again. Right ? I In my data its dynamic value and its in number of thousands. Currently I have solved it by setting different color to PRE, POST And EXP. So its little bit readable. But still looking for solution

Comment: It can work with any numbers of items. Also it can be dynamic with VBA using the worksheet event `Worksheet_PivotTableUpdate`. BTW your solution is the opposite of what you say were aiming to.